# Передача указателя в функцию

Tags: c, функции, указатели, микроконтроллеры, stm32

Пишу программу на чистом Си для микроконтроллера STM32f05. В программе есть функция, которая получает информацию по UART и функция парсинга. Выглядят они так:

```
char Getchar(void)
{
    while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, RXNE) == RESET);
    return USART_ReceiveData(USART1);
}
void USART_IRQ_Interrup(void)
{
    if (USART_GetITStatus(USART1, RXNE))
    {
        //char buffer[255];
        char * buffer = calloc(255, sizeof(char));
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = Getchar();
            if (buffer[i] == '\n') break;
        }
        ProcessFrame(buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }
}
void ProcessFrame(const char * frame)
{
    //Разбираем кадр. Проблемы начинаются здесь.
    //Если сюда передан массив фиксированного размера (как в закомментированном коде),
    //то программа не доходит до этого места. Если отладчиком приостановить программу,
    //то он перейдёт в дизассемблер на метку __exit. Вероятно, произошла недопустимая
    //операция, которая в С++ называется исключением. Поскольку оно не обработано, программа завершилась.
    //Если передан динамический массив, то он содержит непонятные данные. 
    //Они не отображаются отладчиком в watch, но и код неправильно их 
    //обрабатывает. Например, если написать if (buffer[i] == 'A'), 
    //то это условие никогда не будет истинным, 
    //хотя я уверен, что эта буква там содержится.
}
```

Отладка кода под микроконтроллеры часто вызывает трудности: иногда невозможно вывести переменную в watch, поэтому я не могу точно сказать, как именно ведёт себя этот код, но очевидно, что неправильно. И я уверен, что проблема не в микроконтроллере, а в особенностях языка Си. Как же правильно передать указатель в функцию?

Comment: А где собственно передача указателя на функцию?

Приведенный код достаточно простой и чего то страшного я не вижу.

Comment: (Поиграем в телепатов.) А откуда функция `ProcessFrame` знает, сколько именно данных ей передано?

Comment: Можно поподробней описать функции в коде[?][1]


  [1]: http://darkhelp.com.ua/

Comment: @VladD, строка заканчивается символом конца строки '\n'.
@KoVadim, не **указателя на функцию**, а **указателя в функцию** (как аргумент).

Comment: @Alouette: Хорошо. Тогда дайте код, который прячется под комментарием «`//Тут массив заполняется данными`». Указатель на данные вы передаёте правильно, ошибиться негде.

Comment: @VladD, если указатель передаётся правильно, то скорее всего, дело в специфике процессора или реализации библиотечной функции calloc под этот процессор. Тут уже мне самому нужно читать документацию. Но ответ на вопрос я получил: указатель я передаю правильно. Спасибо!
Но если кто-то сталкивался с проблемами выделения памяти в ARM-процессорах, прошу подсказать.

Comment: @Alouette: Предыдущий вариант кода (с `char buffer[255];` и без `free`) был по идее тоже правильный.

Кстати, а хорошо ли в обработчике прерывания блокироваться до изменения статуса? (Я не знаю, никогда не имел дела с embedded.)

Comment: @VladD, конечно, блокироваться до изменения статуса не рекомендуется. Просто я пишу код по памяти, он находится на работе. На самом деле я использовал таймаут: если в течение определённого времени флаг RXNE не поднялся (не поступил новый байт в регистр приёма), считаем, что приём завершён.

Comment: @Alouette, это только предположение (я с этим микроконтроллером не знаком), но может быть проблема с размером стека в обработчике прерываний?

Если эти прерывания не могут быть вложенными (функция `USART_IRQ_Interrup()`), то попробуйте описать статический буфер:

      static char buffer[255];

и передавать в `ProcessFrame()` его.

Comment: @avp: Кстати, интересно, можно ли в обработчиках прерывания использовать `malloc`? Heap-то наверняка нереэнтерабельный.

Comment: @VladD, стандартный malloc наверняка нельзя

 (даже для ненастоящих прерываний).  В конце-концов или рухнет или уйдет в бесконечный цикл (видел как-то такое при обработке SIGCHLD).

Но у автора явно ошибка не в этом.

Comment: @VladD, не знал, что нельзя динамически выделять память в прерывании. Но почему вы думаете, что ошибка не в этом?

Comment: @Alouette, для того, чтобы проявилась *эта* ошибка (в malloc) нужно, чтобы прерывание с последующим вызовом malloc произошло как раз в тот момент, когда в ходе работы внутри malloc нарушена консистетность данных (списков и т.п.), которыми malloc оперирует.

Просто она бы возникала периодически (и непредсказуемо), а не постоянно, как Вы описываете ситуацию.

Comment: @Alouette: Я не уверен, вам лучше стоит расспросить специалистов по вашей платформе. Идея в том, что прерывание может случится во время работы другого `malloc`'а, а значит, связные списки свободных/занятых блоков может быть в неправильном состоянии. Но это сравнительно редкое событие, так что если ошибка проявляется _каждый раз_, то проблема не в этом.

Comment: @avp: почти синхронно :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Судя по названию ф-ции **USART_IRQ_Interrup** - обработчик прерывания. И в нем автор занимается динамическим выделением памяти (calloc/free). Я, конечно, не претендую на звание "лучший программист-под-STM 2014", но проблемы, скорее всего, именно изза этого. Выделяйте постоянный буфер для данных. Задача кода в прерывании - забрать всё (или почти всё) из UART'а и свалить как можно быстрее. Ставьте там флаг, периодически проверяйте его в основном цикле, и в основном же цикле делайте парсинг. Это немного усложняет конструкцию буфера, т.к. он должен быть кольцевым, с проверкой на переполнение. Размер буфера выбираем исходя из того, какой трафик предполагается через UART, а так же, возможно, в зависимости от протокола обмена. Вот такая вот асинхронщина...

Answer (score 0):

В итоге всё решилось отключением оптимизации.

Comment: Эээ... Что-то не то. Не имеет права с оптимизацией и без неё вести себя по-разному. Единственная возможная причина — у вас где-то ещё undefined behaviour, и со включенной оптимизацией оптимизатор ломает программу.

Перепроверьте. В крайнем случае сравните ассемблерный код. Наверняка ошибка не исправлена, а лишь прикрыта.